# "figurative" vs "metaphorical"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, terminology, figurative-language

What is  the difference between two these terms? 
Are they interchangeably used? 
Because when I sometimes look at the dictionary, I see this term, figurative, attached to some words which can be used in a figurative way.

Comment: It is not surprising that you see the term _figurative_ used to describe words that can be used in a figurative way! Most English language thesauruses provide _figurative_ as a _synonym_ of _metaphorical,_ so in most cases they can be used interchangeably. Did you consult a thesaurus?

Comment: @P.E.Dant A thesaurus lists *similar* words, but that doesn't always mean they're synonyms! While the words *are* very similar, they are not quite identical, and none of my dictionaries list them as synonyms. Merriam-webster online's definition 2a is considered a synonym, but there is also 2b which is relevant to this context, which is not interchangeable with metaphorical.

Comment: @Lijero If a word is a synonym of another word, it's **almost** or **completely** identical to the other word in a certain sense. My thesaurus lists the two words as synonyms, and the OED treats them pretty much as synonyms in certain senses. At any rate, there aren't that many "true" or "absolute" synonyms, and even then the difference is in collocations/register/dialect/etc. Nevertheless, I concede that thesauri often play fast and loose with the word *synonym*.

Comment: @userr2684291 Thesauruses exist to assist writers and scrabble players. They aren't meant to be "serious" research sources, I think. Our questioner could spend many and many an hour scrutinizing the differences between the two words, but it is their _similarity_ that is the core of his question. In common parlance, when someone says _"I'm speaking figuratively,"_ her meaning is identical to _"I'm speaking metaphorically,"_ unless she is a poet or a didact addressing a specific figure of speech.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I agree. I was simply pointing out the fact that *synonym* doesn't only mean "identical", but could also mean "almost identical". I believe Lijero here was trying to say the opposite – that since (oh no) they're not entirely identical, they aren't synonyms and, consequently, their dictionaries (thesauri?) don't list them as such. My final remark goes further than that; what I was trying to say is that thesauri often extend the definition of *synonym* even beyond the one described above.

Comment: If you are keen to make a distinction, a metaphor implies a comparison whereas a figurative use of a word re-applies a concept to an abstraction. For example, to "seize" an opportunity. Of course, you could also describe that as a metaphor: taking advantage of an opportunity is like grabbing hold of it in your hand. That's why speaking figuratively and metaphorically are functionally synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are. The two words may have different connotations, since **metaphor** sometimes can refer to phrases like *a sea of troubles* specifically (as opposed to *organized chaos*, an example of oxymoron, or *cheeks like roses*, an example of simile), but **figurative** and **metaphorical** are generally interchangeable.

Comment: Actually similes (and analogies) are a kind of metaphor (see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/similes-and-metaphors-are-similes-a-subset-of-metaphors ), but overall this answer is correct.

Comment: How do you suggest I correct it, then?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, since my comment is more of an FYI than any criticism.  I remember (long ago) my high school English teacher also told me that a simile is not a metaphor so I was surprised to learn that this is not *necessarily* true, and "metaphor" is an umbrella term for all such *figurative* comparisons or substitutions.

Comment: @Andrew This issue also came up on the OP's comment thread, so I've changed my answer to discuss typical usage instead of technical truth, albeit perhaps to some cost of readability.

Comment: The OP asked: _"Are they interchangeably used?"_ The answer is that they are. He doesn't ask whether they are precisely synonymous. He's learning to speak and read English, not studying to be a linguist or lexicographer!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I believe I've edited the confusing and controversial aspects of my answer, if you'd like to revisit your downvote.

Comment: Well done. I'd lead with the "Yes, they are" and follow with the exceptions, but that's style.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I think it is the same thing when you say they are synonyms or interchangeably used. No, I am not just learning to read and speak, but to be a good writer. Because I am looking forward to writing a book in English, And i want to know grammatically every thing of English language.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo By _read and speak_ I meant also _to write,_ of course. There are very few "perfect" synonyms in any language. There are very subtle possible distinctions between the two words which might be important to understand in a technical setting, but as you now understand, you can with confidence use the two words interchangeably in most contexts.